# remix fund me gas estimation error

Tags: solidity, remix

Q)Why am I getting this error ? "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction > execution will likely fail"
-> withdraw function is showing infinite gas in remix ide

error:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). 
The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted: You need to spend more ETH!","errorData":"0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001b596f75206e65656420746f207370656e64206d6f726520455448210000000000","id":1456657711424373}
```

code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "./PriceConverter.sol";

error NotOwner();

contract FundMe {
using PriceConverter for uint256;

mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
address[] public funders;

// Could we make this constant?  /* hint: no! We should make it immutable! */
address public /* immutable */ i_owner;
uint256 public constant MINIMUM_USD = 50 * 10 ** 18;

constructor() {
    i_owner = msg.sender;
}

function fund() public payable {
    require(msg.value.getConversionRate() >= MINIMUM_USD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
    // require(PriceConverter.getConversionRate(msg.value) >= MINIMUM_USD, "You need to spend more ETH!");
    addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    funders.push(msg.sender);
}

function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
    // ETH/USD price feed address of Sepolia Network.
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306);
    return priceFeed.version();
}

modifier onlyOwner {
    // require(msg.sender == owner);
    if (msg.sender != i_owner) revert NotOwner();
    _;
}

function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
    for (uint256 funderIndex=0; funderIndex < funders.length; funderIndex++){
        address funder = funders[funderIndex];
        addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
    }
    funders = new address[](0);
    (bool callSuccess, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    require(callSuccess, "Call failed");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says `You need to spend more ETH` which is coming directly from the `fund` function.
The `fund` function requires you to send 50 ethers, make sure to send it while calling the function.

You need to input 50 ethers here in the value field while calling the function.

[image]

Comment: error solved, thank you @Zartaj Afser

Comment: Awesome, mark it as an answer :)